# Hacer que un mapa ocupe toda la pantalla y regrese al tamaño original

Tags: swift2, swift

Hola estoy intentando hacer que al tocar un mapa de una de mis vistas, el mapa ocupe toda la pantalla y con otro toque se reduzca a tu tamaño original sin que desaparezca.

Esta es la estructura de mis vistas:
[image: jerarquia]

Y al ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VistaDetalleNivelUnoVC.ModifySize))
    mapLocation.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}

func ModifySize () {
    print("Full")
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    mapLocation.userInteractionEnabled = true
    mapLocation.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    mapLocation.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(mapLocation)
    print(mapLocation.frame)

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VistaDetalleNivelUnoVC.dismissFullscreenImage(_:)))
    mapLocation.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

al pulsar sobre el mapa se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando vuelvo a tocar sobre el desaparece por completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De que manera puedo hacer que el mapa ocupe toda la pantalla por delante de la otra vista que contiene el UIImageView y como puedo regresarlo a su tamaño original con un solo toque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces esto siempre eliminaras el mapa

```
func dismissFullscreenImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Lo que necesitas es redimensionar el mapa de nuevo no borrarlo de la superview , asi que simplmente haz lo mismo que haces para hacerlo grande que es cambiar su **frame**

Comment: Hola, si esa parte ya ha quedado solucionada. La parte que aun me da batalla es que el mapa ocupe toda la pantalla. Es posible que pueda ocupar toda la pantalla aun cuando esta embebido en un view mas pequeño?.

Comment: Si el mapView esta dentro de una View lo mas grande que se puede hacer sera a lo maximo de grande que sea su view, por lo tanto haz tambien más grande la view que contiene el mapa

Comment: Gracias @Alejandro he movido el Mapa a una view independiente y tienes razon he tenido que agrandar el view que lo contiene y ya ha quedado.